# How to make .NET primary output for installer only create program executable?

Tags: installation

I use Visual Studio 2013 Professional.

I installed [Solution Dependency Viewer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b11824d0-d942-4863-99f8-e1884f26387a?SRC=VSIDE) and upon installation and restarting Visual Studio it deleted *everything* in my solution save the folders. Both the project and wizard I made for it. Kinda irritated by that. Went and grabbed a backup of my solution and fixed everything for my program. For the installer though, I had made a folder for the primary output which was for the User's Programs Menu. Initially, the primary output was just the executable and app.config file. I made a filter for the app.config file and the installer would successfully create a folder and the executable in the start menu program folders. After this extension decided to delete everything, every time I try creating the primary output for the start menu program folders it generates the executable and all the dependencies with it. I can delete the executable, but not all the DLLs that also get generated.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say specifically how I did it, but coming in the next day and recompiling some things and then the project output was the executable itself. I deleted the app.config file so the filter wasn't needed.